# Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, entity

I have two list of class, for example :

```
public class ListA
{
    public string FinAccCompleteCode { get; set; }

    public string FinAccCompleteDesc { get; set; }
}
public class ListB
{
    public string FinAccCompleteCode { get; set; }

    public string FinAccCompleteCodeDesc { get; set; }
}
```

I'll get items of ListA where them exists in Class ListB, also i use the bellow code

```
db.ListA.Where(a => ListB.Any(t => t.FinAccCompleteCode == a.FinAccCompleteCode)).ToList();
```

but occure this error :
Unable to create a constant value of type 'ListB'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: ListB do not have `FinAccCompleteDesc`. `FinAccCompleteCode` is repeated.

Comment: Have you used Contains in the query?

Comment: inside the query you show there is ListB,shouldnt it be db.ListB?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used bellow method

```
var result=db.ListA.Where(a => ListB.Contains(a.FinAccCompelteCode)).ToList();
```

I don't know , what is difrence between both code ?